# Converting a time_t to NSDate object?

Tags: nsdate, time-t

Is there any method provided by Apple or any technique that can convert a time_t type variable to an NSDate object?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`NSDate *someDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:some_time_t]`